# Ошибка при смене языка интерфейса системы через cmd (Set-UILangFallBack)

Tags: windows, cmd, locale, multilanguage

Ввожу C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /image:C:\test\offline /Set-UILangFallBack:ru-RU
Результат
Ошибка: 3

Не удалось получить доступ к образу.
Убедитесь, что путь к образу и каталог Windows образа существуют и учетная запись обладает правами на чтение папки.

Файл журнала DISM находится по адресу C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log

Answer (score 0):

/Set-UILangFallback:<имя_языка>
Устанавливает в автономном образе Windows базовый язык по умолчанию для системного пользовательского интерфейса. **Этот параметр используется только в случае, если язык, заданный параметром /Set-UILang, является языком с частичной локализацией.**

/Set-UILangFallback:<имя_языка> **определяет имя языка, устанавливаемого в качестве базового языка по умолчанию, например en-US.**